# How to set different paths to different images on the same views block

Tags: views, media, uri

I have a situation where I have a block with 3 Images and links in the front page set in a block (drupal 7)
and I am trying to make each image and link to point to a different section in the site
but I can't :( I only managed to make them all point to the same page or to divide each to its own block (with views)
but then it doesn't look so good visually...

is there a solution for that?
Thanks

Comment: Are you creating your block with views? Are you using the images and links as fields in the view? (I suppose, you have the [Link module](http://drupal.org/project/link/) installed, to create a custom link field for the content-type where your image is also located). If yes, you can simply override the output of the fields in the field settings.

Comment: Yes I'm doing it exactly like you said 
I set the block to take the fields from a content using views and I cant manage to separate the content, whatever I do effects all the images and I want each of them to point to a different url
Thanks for your help, I'm new to drupal

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is a step by step "how to manage this" ;)

Step 1: be sure to have the content type for your images containing a field "link", where you can add the link to your specific page section.

[image: screen_1]

Step 2: Add some content with image and URL to page section (e.g: node/13)

[image: screen_2]

Step 3: Make sure you have some nodes like this:

[image: screen_3]

Step 4: Create a new view for the block you want to fill with your content-type:

[image: screen_4]

Step 5: Add the fields you want to show to the view: (here: the field for the image and the field for the link). If the link should be shown seperate from the image as well, you'll have to add the field for the link twice, because we'll "pass over" one link to the image)

[image: screen_5]

Step 6: Now re-arrange the fields so that the order is the following. This is important, because the image field will hold a replacement pattern of the above Link field (which is excluded from display, because we don't want the link to show up, we only need its data).

[image: screen_6]

Step 7: Now configure the first image field "excluded (mylink)" so that it is excluded from display and rewrites the output of the field with the replacement pattern for the "Raw url" value:

[image: screen_7]

Step 8: Now configure the image field like this. Mark "Output this field as a link" and use the replacement pattern for the above link field "[field_mylink]".

That's it. Now you have a view that pulls the URL from the content type and puts it on the image of it.

[image]